# Ordinated Container with key

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I'm looking for a container which is basically a list where each node is composed by an element and a function of the element itself ( < x,f(x) > ) where x and f(x) are integers.

This container should allow me to insert in a ordered way where the order is provided by f(x).
Is there anything like that in the STL?

Comment: Thanks for all the answer, in my case anyway I can get same values of f(x) for different values of x.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) and use `f(x)` as key.

```
#include <map>

int f(int);

int n = ....;
std::map<int,int> m;
m.insert(std::make_pair(f(n), n));

int i = ...;
m[f(i)] = i;
```

Another option is to use [std::set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) with a suitable comparator function, as has been suggested in other answers. However you must make sure your comparator implements [strict weak ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering), and this depends on the characteristics of your function `f(int)`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can

```
int foo(int x );

struct mycustomcompare {
  bool operator() (const int& lhs, const int& rhs) const
  {return foo(lhs) < foo(rhs);}
};


int main()
{
    std::set<int,mycustomcompare> myset;
    myset.insert( 1 );
    myset.insert( 2 );
}
```

Of course if foo(2) and foo(3) return same value only one of them will be inserted. You can use multiset if you domain has the problem

```
int foo(int x )
{
    return x % 2 ==0;
}

struct mycustomcompare {
  bool operator() (const int& lhs, const int& rhs) const
  {return foo(lhs) < foo(rhs);}
};


int main()
{
    std::multiset<int,mycustomcompare> myset;
    myset.insert( 1 );
    myset.insert( 2 );
    myset.insert( 3);
    myset.insert( 4);
    myset.insert( 5);
    myset.insert( 6);

}
```

In the above example all the odd elements will be in the first half of the set. Or you can simply use a vector and sort with a compare function

```
int foo(int x )
{
    return x % 2 ==0;
}

struct mycustomcompare 
{
    bool operator() (const int& lhs, const int& rhs) const
    {return foo(lhs) < foo(rhs);}
};


int main()
{

    std::vector<int> myvector;

    myvector.push_back( 5);
    myvector.push_back( 1 );
    myvector.push_back( 6);
    myvector.push_back( 2 );
    myvector.push_back( 3);
    myvector.push_back( 4);

    std::sort( myvector.begin() , myvector.end() , mycustomcompare() );
}
```

If evaluation of f(x) is expensive you can also add some state to your compare object.

Answer (score 2):

At this point, there are two different answers suggesting the use of a `std::set` with a custom comparator and a `std::map` that maps `f(x)` to `x`. I would actually go for a third option: `std::set< std::pair<int,int> >` where the pair are `(f(x),x)`.

The advantage over the `std::map<>` is that while it holds the same information, it ensures that `x` is not modified, and thus guarantees the invariant that iterating over the map will always yield pairs of `(f(x),x)`. The advantage over a `std::set<int, cmp>` where `cmp` is `f` is that the function need only be calculated once, with the value being present in the container (which might or not have an impact, depending on the cost of `f`), and additionally

The other difference of this approach with the others (which might be positive or negative) is that it naturally allows for multiple values of `x` mapping to the same `f(x)`, as the order on `std::pair<>` is lexicographical, the container will store all such pairs, in an order that is first determined by `f(x)`, and then by `x` for those `x` values for which `f(x)` is the same (i.e. `(0,1), (0,3), (1,2)` assuming that `f(1) == f(3) == 0` and `f(2) == 1`.

If you cannot allow for such duplicates (i.e if you only want to have one element for each `f(x)` value), then you can add a custom comparator that tests only the `first` value of each pair.